# how to get the total number count based on if condition using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here i am using AJAX ,it is working fine,in success function i am getting all status values like Active,ACTIVE_DRAFT,Pending.i want to take only status equal to ACTIVE so i am writing one if condition upto working fine after i want to take the count like how many status is active like that so i am trying like this but i am not able to get the count,i am get **console.log(count);** the string length of id.

```js
$.ajax({
  url: 'http://example.com/api/get/mylisting',
  type: 'GET',
  contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
  success: function(active_draft_sell, textStatus, xhr) {
    var count = 0 ;
    $.each(active_draft_sell, function(key, value) {
        var status = value.status;
        var listingtype = value.listingtype;

        if (status == "ACTIVE")) {
        var id = value.id;
        console.log(value.id);
        var count = id.length;
         count++;
        console.log(count);
      }
    });
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://example.com/api/get/mylisting',  
    type: 'GET',
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    success: function(active_draft_sell,textStatus, xhr) {

        var count = 0;
        $.each( active_draft_sell, function( key, value ) {
            var status = value.status;
            var listingtype = value.listingtype;
            if(status == "ACTIVE"){ 
                count++;
                console.log(count);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Also, why do you want to get the same value ('ACTIVE') multiple times?

Comment: I am not getting correct answer ,based on if condition i have 2 rows but your code  console.log(count); it showing 1 only

Comment: I want to take count and display like 2 properties is active like that

Comment: Can you please console.log the active_draft_sell and give us the values inside, and also what the wanted result is?

Answer (score 0):

If you have multiple values coming back you need to update a variable outside of the `$.each` function in order to track all items that have the `Active` status.

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'http://example.com/api/get/mylisting',  
  type: 'GET',
  contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
  success: function(active_draft_sell,textStatus, xhr) {
    var count = 0;
    $.each( active_draft_sell, function( key, value ) {
        var status = value.status;
        var listingtype = value.listingtype;

        if(status == "ACTIVE") {   
            count++;                
        }
    });
    console.log(count);
  }
});
```

Comment: Also, you have a typo in the line `if(status == "ACTIVE")){...}` notice you have 2 parentheses.  You only need one as I have in my answer.

Comment: Any possible anser i need the count of inside the loop

Comment: You need the count of _what_ inside the loop?  What are you trying to count?

Answer (score 0):

Try this. You will get count inside the loop.

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'http://example.com/api/get/mylisting',
  type: 'GET',
  contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
  success: function(active_draft_sell, textStatus, xhr) {

    var count = 0 ;
    for(var i = 0; i < active_draft_sell.length; i++) {
       if(active_draft_sell[i].status == "ACTIVE"){
          count++;
       }
    } 

    $.each(active_draft_sell, function(key, value) {
        var status = value.status;
        var listingtype = value.listingtype;

        console.log(count);
      }
    });
  }
});
```